# declare -A fake_declaration=() does not work in MacOsX

Tags: bash

I have a script that does not works on MacOsX. But it is not a real problem: I can use a `try catch` avoiding strange behaviors. But always reamains the fact that I want to make my scripts compatibles in all environments I need.

```
{
    declare -A fake_declaration=()
} || {
    clear
    printf "\n\n\nThis script cannot work here\n\n"
    exit
}
```

Exists a workaround to works with associative arrays also in MacOsX?

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? `declare -A` requires `bash 4.0+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associative array feature was introduced in BASH version `4.0`. Default OSX ships with BASH version `3.2.xy`

You can check your bash version using:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

For me it shows:

```
3.2.57(1)-release
```

You can tweak your pseudo script like this to make it work with or without associative arrays without producing an error:

```
{ declare -A fake_declaration=(); } 2>/dev/null || 
    { clear; printf "\n\n\nThis script cannot work here\n\n"; }
```

**Alternatively** you can use [`home brew` package](http://brew.sh/) to install BASH `4.3+` with all other gnu goodies.